# Selenium Webdriver - Java, Browser shows message "ERROR: This page has expired. Please cancel this operation and try again" on button click

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, browser, automated-tests

When I run the test method `runSuite()`, everything is fine till the last line of the method:

```
button.click(); // clicks the button on page
```

The above statement results in the page expired issue. 
I get the following message on the browser window:

> ERROR: This page has expired. Please cancel this operation and try again.

I tried playing around browser cache, but that didn't help.

```
package com.swtestacademy.webdriver;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.Timeouts;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.junit.*;

import com.util.MockLoginClient;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class MainTest {

      private WebDriver driver;
      private String baseUrl;
      private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

      @Before
      public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockLoginClient.instance().authenticateAsHcrCaseWorker();
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:/IEDriverServer_x64_3.4.0/IEDriverServer.exe");
        //driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.addPreference("log", "{level: trace}");
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
        capabilities.setCapability("moz:firefoxOptions", options);
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ELEMENT_SCROLL_BEHAVIOR, 1);
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_APPLICATION_CACHE, "applicationCacheEnabled");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64/geckodriver.exe");
        //ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
        //profile.getProfile("default");
        FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
        ffprofile.setPreference("browser.cache.disk.enable", true);
        ffprofile.setPreference("browser.cache.memory.enable", true);
        ffprofile.setPreference("browser.cache.offline.enable", true);
        ffprofile.setPreference("network.http.use-cache", true);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);//ffprofile);

        //driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

        baseUrl = "http://localhost:8082/";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        //driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       // driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(3000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        driver.get(baseUrl + "/Curam/AppController.do");
      }

      @Test
      public void test() throws Exception {
        driver.get(baseUrl + "/Curam/AppController.do");
        driver.findElement(By.id("app-sections-container-dc_tablist_DefaultAppSection-sbc_tabLabel")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.dojoxExpandoIcon.dojoxExpandoIconLeft")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_layout_AccordionPane_1_button_title")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#dijit_layout_AccordionPane_1 > ul > li > a.curam-content-pane-single-link")).click();


        driver.getWindowHandle();
        Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
        Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            iterator.next();
        }
        //driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // switch to popup window

        driver.findElement(By.id("curam_ModalDialog_0"));
        driver.findElement(By.className("dijitDialogPaneContent"));
        driver.findElement(By.id("curam_ModalUIMController_0"));
        driver.findElement(By.className("contentPanelFrameWrapper"));
        driver.switchTo().frame("iframe-curam_ModalDialog_0");
        driver.findElement(By.tagName("html"));
        driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
        driver.findElement(By.id("content"));
        driver.findElement(By.id("mainForm"));
        driver.findElement(By.id("modal-actions-panel"));
        // driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='modal-actions-panel']/div[2]/a/span/span/span")).click();
        WebElement nxtBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("__o3btn.NEXTPAGE_2"));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        nxtBtn.click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='modal-actions-panel']/div[2]/a[2]/span/span/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("__o3btn.SAVE_0")).click();
      }

      @After
      public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        //driver.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
          fail(verificationErrorString);
        }
      }

      @Test
    public void runSuite() throws InterruptedException {
          System.out.println(driver);
            WebElement xy = driver.findElement(By.id("app-sections-container-dc_tablist_DefaultAppSection-sbc_tabLabel"));
            xy.click();
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.dojoxExpandoIcon.dojoxExpandoIconLeft")).click();
            WebElement personSearchLink = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Person…"));
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            personSearchLink.click();
            WebElement appStc = driver.findElement(By.id("DefaultAppSection-stc"));
            WebElement djtTab = appStc.findElement(By.className("dijitTabPaneWrapper"));
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            WebElement tpChldWrapper = djtTab.findElement(By.className("dijitTabContainerTopChildWrapper"));
            WebElement lyoutCntntPane = tpChldWrapper.findElement(By.id("dojox_layout_ContentPane_1"));
            WebElement tbWrpr = lyoutCntntPane.findElement(By.className("tab-wrapper"));
            WebElement noDtlsPnl = tbWrpr.findElement(By.className("no-details-panel"));
            WebElement cntntAreaCntnr = noDtlsPnl.findElement(By.className("content-area-container"));
            WebElement fstUIMCntrlr = cntntAreaCntnr.findElement(By.id("curam_FastUIMController_1"));
            WebElement cntntPnlFrmWrpr = fstUIMCntrlr.findElement(By.className("contentPanelFrameWrapper"));
            WebElement iFrameElmnt = cntntPnlFrmWrpr.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
            driver.switchTo().frame(iFrameElmnt);
            WebElement inputText = driver.findElement(By.id("__o3id0"));
            Thread.sleep(100);
            inputText.sendKeys("24684");
           // Thread.sleep(4000);
            WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Search"));
            button.click(); 
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could see the issue. This behavior is seen for Firefox and Internet explorer only  and not for chrome.

The solution would be to check the default desired capabilities for Chrome driver and set the same for Firefox driver or IE driver.

Easier Solution: Switch to Chrome Driver.